# I get blocked when I try to scrape with RSelenium

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I try to scrape a website using the following code:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

rD<-rsDriver(browser = 'firefox', port = 4875L)
remDr<-rD$client

input_galaxus<-c('https://www.galaxus.ch/8606656','https://www.galaxus.ch/9796481','https://www.galaxus.ch/10592688')

vec_galaxus<-vector()
i=0

for (j in input_galaxus){
  remDr$navigate(j)
  
            i=i+1
            try(vec_galaxus[i]<-read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])%>%
                  html_nodes('div strong')%>%
                  html_text()%>%
                  nth(5))
            Sys.sleep(runif(1, min=5, max=10))
}
```

But when the loop turns to the second webpage, it cannot acces the website anymore.

Can someone help me out how to fix this problem?

Thank you so much!

Comment: What are you trying to extract from the page?

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with an `rvest` session - no need for Selenium.  Just remove the RSelenium lines and replace your `for` loop with

```
sess <- session(input_galaxus[1])             #to start the session
for (j in input_galaxus){
  sess <- sess %>% session_jump_to(j)         #jump to URL
  
  i=i+1
  try(vec_galaxus[i] <- read_html(sess) %>%   #can read direct from sess
        html_nodes('div strong') %>%
        html_text() %>%
        nth(5))
  Sys.sleep(runif(1, min=5, max=10))
}


vec_galaxus
[1] " 399.–" " 660.–" " 931.–"
```